# Closing Windows forms

Tags: vb.net

I want to close my windows form when it loses focus.

I mapped `Me.Close()` function inside lost focus object but when losing focus, the form gets minimised.

[image: code]

Comment: Showing all relevant code would be good in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Me.Close() close only the form and not the program itself. If this is the only active form then it will get minimized so that the program can still be active. I guess you mean *Application.Exit()* which actually close the application.

Comment: I tried with Application.Exit(), but still i was able to see the form when shifting screens using Alt+Tab.

Comment: Try `End` instead of `Application.Exit()` @KanianMCBuilding

Comment: `If this is the only active form then it will get minimized so that the program can still be active`  Huh?  The form gets minimized because the OP has code somewhere that minimizes it.

Comment: I have edited my question with the image of the code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Deactivate if dealing with forms, like:

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    MsgBox("Lost focus")
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited my question with the image of the code.